# How to estimate the hazard function?

Tags: survival, cox-model

I model the survival data with a piece wise constant exponential distribution at time t. Let R be the total number of the population at time t, and D be the number of deaths observed at time t+dt. So, we may estimate the local hazard function as D/dt from the Poisson process or as D/R from the Kaplan-Meier model. Could we make connections between the two formulas or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: "a piece wise constant". Who is constant?

Comment: Yes! It's constant in the interval [t, t+dt].

Comment: "constant exponential distribution"?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean that you assume a piece-wise exponential distribution of survival times, which implies a piece-wise constant hazard function. The respective model is called the **Piece-wise exponential model (PEM)**.

There is a connection between the PEM and Cox PH, in fact they are equivalent in some situations (see example [here](https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/articles/basics.html) and the Whitehead 1980 reference therein).

However, it is usually better to use an extension of the PEM, the **Piece-wise exponential additive (mixed) model (PAMM)** that can be estimated using GAMMs.

I wrote an R package **`pammtools`** specifically to do so. 
See this vignette to get started with PEM and PAMM: https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/articles/baseline.html

In the articles section there are many more examples (and comparisons to other models, e.g. `survival::coxph`: https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/articles/